# Get clientOriginalName in Laravel View

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel view where a user uploads multiple files.  My controller takes those files and places them in a folder in public/storage.  The file name is the client's original file name,  I am trying to have the view display that original file name dynamically (instead of the temporary path) and then link to that file.   I have the following code:

```
<a class='col-6' href="/download/{{ $plansubmission->id }}/{{$plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 }}">{{ $plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 }}</a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/download/{folder}/{id}', 'DownloadsController@getDownload');
```

DownloadsController:

```
class DownloadsController extends Controller
{      
    public function getDownload($folder, $id){
        //PDF file is stored under project/public/download/info.pdf
        $pathToFile=public_path(). "\storage\\$folder\\$id";
        // return Response::download($file);
        return response()->file($pathToFile);
    }
}
```

I can type the proper path into the URL and the download works.  But the link from the view does not as it links to a local file store.

Comment: when you are storing the files and saving the record, you need to get the new filename after storing it not the temporary location name

Comment: Thank you.  I'm just not quite sure how to do that.  Here is how I am saving the file:

                        Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
                            $folder,
                            $file,
                            $file->getClientOriginalName()
                        );

Comment: what are you saving in the database? sounds like you are saving `$file`, which would give you the temporary file path ... edit your question and provide that controller method

Answer (score 0):

If you add a name to your route, something like this:

> Route::get('/download/{folder}/{id}', 'DownloadsController@getDownload')->name('pdfDownload');

then in the view you can call `route()` like this:

```
route('pdfDownload', [$plansubmission->id, $plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1]);
```

this will automatically bind the values to the route and to your url.

more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes). I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I probably should do that.  But, the problem I am having is that my file is saved as the original client name (i.e. TestFile.pdf) and when I return $plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1, that just gives me a filepath like C:\xampp\tmp\phpE05A.tmp.  As a result, I cannot make a link to the file because I cannot get the proper filename for the URL.